# If $(a,b) = 1$, show that $(a-b,a^2+ab+b^2)=1 \text{ or } 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I have a question...We know that $(a,b)=1$ and we want to show that $(a-b,a^2+ab+b^2)=1 \text{ or } 3$.How can I show this??
I thought that we could suppose that $(a-b,a^2+ab+b^2)=d$.Then we know that $d|a-b$ and $d|,a^2+ab+b^2$.But how can I continue??

Comment: I suppose (a,b) and a|b are modulo operators? Can you pl. confirm. thanks

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora How can $gcd$ be, it finds the largest common divisor using double recursion and division, neither is division. Modulo operator uses in turn the division operation to yield a congruence (residue) class.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\,\ (a\!-\!b,a^2\!+ab+b^2)\overset{\color{#c00}{(1)}} = (a\!-\!b,\color{#c0f}{3b^2})\overset{\color{#0a0}{(2)}} = (a\!-\!b,3),\ $ by $\ \color{#0a0}{(2)\!:\ }(a\!-\!b,b) = (a,b) = 1,\ $ and by

$\, \color{#c00}{(1)\!:}\, \ (a\!-\!b,c) = (a\!-\!b,d) \,$ if $\,c\equiv d\pmod{\!a\!-\!b},\,$ and $\,{\rm mod}\ a\!-\!b\!:\ a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, a^2\!+ab+b^2\equiv \color{#c0f}{3b^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is useful to try dividing these things out. So here (treating the quadratic as a polynomial in $a$ and using the division algorithm for polynomials) $$a^2+ab+b^2=(a-b)(a+2b)+3b^2$$
you should be able to make some progress from there ...

Comment: I did the following: [since $a^2+ab+b^2=(a-b)^2+3ab$]
$$d|a-b \Rightarrow d|(a-b)^2$$
$$d|a^2+ab+b^2 \Rightarrow d|(a-b)^2+3ab$$
So $$d|(a-b)^2+3ab-(a-b)^2 \Rightarrow d|3ab$$
Is this correct so far?? How can I continue?

Comment: Look at the form I have given and assume that $d|a^2+ab+b^2$ and $d|a-b$. What else must $d$ divide?

Comment: $$d|a^2+ab+b^2 \Rightarrow d|(a-b)(a+2b)+3b^2$$
Since $d|a-b$ should $d$ also divide $3b^2$?

Comment: @evinda Indeed (Bill Dubuque's approach leads in the same direction). Now you need to think why $d$ must be a factor of $3$ and can't share a factor with $b$.

Comment: To show that it cannot share a factor with $b$ do I have to use that $(a,b)=1$?

Comment: @evinda well that's a piece of information we've not yet used yet - so give it a try

Comment: If $d|b$ and we know that $d|a-b$,  $d$ should divide also $a$, (d|a). So $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, but $(a,b)=1$, so $d=1$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

$d|a-b$,$d|a^2+ab+b^2$ and $a^2+ab+b^2=(a-b)^2+3ab$ imply that
$$d|3ab,d|3a(a^2+ab+b^2)=3a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2,d|3ab(a-b)=3a^2b-3ab^2,d|2a(3ab).$$
Hence, $$d|3a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+3a^2b-3ab^2-6a^2b=3a^3$$ and similarly $d|3b^3$ and now 
$$d\le(3a^3,3b^3)=3(a^3,b^3)=3.$$ so $d=1\,\text{or}\,2\,\text{or}\,3$, but $d$ can't be $2$, since in this case $a^3$ and $b^3$ must be two even numbers and $(a^3,b^3)\neq1$. (Note that $(a,b)=1$ implies $(a^3,b^3)=1$)